# How can i make my 2 radiobutton center and away from my text?

Tags: html

I'm doing a form that includes texts and radio buttons. I wanted to make the radio buttons away from my text and center in a position together so it look neat, but no matter how I put float or margin to 1 of my button , it doesn't work. When I try to put in the html, the text didn't move. How!!!

```
<label for="Process">Which Process to Add?</label><br>
                        <tr><td rowspan="2">Printing (39 x 55)</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="process1" value="Yes" class="Mar"/>Yes</td>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="process1" value="No" checked="checked" class="Mar"/>No</td></tr><br>

                        <tr><td rowspan="2">Printing (28 x 40 / 20 x 28)</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="process2" value="Yes"/>Yes</td>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="process2" value="No" checked="checked"/>No</td></tr><br>

                        <tr><td rowspan="2">Injet Printing</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="process3" value="Yes"/>Yes</td>
                        <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="process3" value="No" checked="checked"/>No</td></tr><br>
```

[image]

Comment: Its not a php question then why did you tagged it as php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html markup structure is not correct. Try below codes:

```html
<label for="Process">Which Process to Add?</label>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:200px;">Printing (39 x 55)</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process1" value="Yes" class="Mar">Yes</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process1" value="No" checked="checked" class="Mar">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Printing (28 x 40 / 20 x 28)</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process2" value="Yes">Yes</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process2" value="No" checked="checked">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Injet Printing</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process3" value="Yes">Yes</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process3" value="No" checked="checked">No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" style="width:200px;">Printing (39 x 55)</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process1" value="Yes" class="Mar">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process1" value="No" checked="checked" class="Mar">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Printing (28 x 40 / 20 x 28)</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process2" value="Yes">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process2" value="No" checked="checked">No</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Injet Printing</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process3" value="Yes">Yes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" name="process3" value="No" checked="checked">No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank!!! it really works! sorry for the structure cause I get this structure references from another creator also :(

Comment: What exactly *did* you do?